# WEB_CALLBACK_URI Does Not Match Expected URIs Square POS API

Tags: android, html, square-connect

I'm using an Acer Chromebook R11 in Dev channel (v 60.x) to develop an HTML5 POS app with Square. I'm trying to fire a basic Android intent with a hyperlink, like so:

```
<a target="_blank" href="intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.browser_fallback_url=**my website**;S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=**my website's main index.php* file*;S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID=**my ID**;S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0;i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT=100;S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=USD;S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CASH,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_OTHER;end">Send me $</a>
```

Square POS is giving the following error: The WEB_CALLBACK_URI parameter does not match any of the expected web callback URIs.

What does this even mean?

Comment: To the person who downvoted this, could you at least provide an answer or feedback as to why you thought this was a bad question? I cannot even find this error documented in Square's developer portal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set your web callback in the dashboard yet? If not here's how.

---

1. Go to your app dashboard https://connect.squareup.com/apps
2. Click on your app and then "Point of Sale API"
3. Put your desired `WEB_CALLBACK_URI` on the bottom of the page where you see "Web Callback URLs" and click "Save".

Comment: I did not know this, and the documentation page I was viewing didn't say anything about this. Thank you!